# Error Array index out of bound when i m add the object in array list

Tags: java

**Here is my code when i m adding the object in array list error display Exception in thread "main" `

```
**java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException :1**`
 `**at Customer.withDrawal(Customer.java:47**`)
  **at Customer.displayMenu(Customer.java:19)**
  **at  AtmTest.main(AtmTest.java:6)**
```

when is occur i don't know what is the problem but please help me bcz its my software of atm machine due to this error i cannot do work of next function.**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Customer{
static String cavailablebal;
Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList witharraylist=new ArrayList();
public void displayMenu()
{
System.out.println ("1----Withdraw Cash");
System.out.println ("2----Cash Transfer");
System.out.println ("3----Deposit Cash");
System.out.println ("4----Display Balance");
System.out.println ("5----Exit ");
System.out.println("Enter your choice");
char choice1=reader.next().charAt(0);
switch(choice1)
{
case'1':
withDrawal();
break;
}
}//end displayMenu

public void withDrawal()
{

String id,accountid,name,type,pamount,status;
String actualbal;

char choice1,choice2,confirm;
int withdrawalbal,availablebal;
int cactualbal;
Login obj2=new Login();
try
{

FileReader fr=new FileReader("account.txt");
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
String fileread=br.readLine();
System.out.println(fileread);
String tokens[];
while (fileread!=null)
{
tokens=fileread.split(",");
id=tokens[0];
accountid=tokens[1];
name=tokens[2];
type=tokens[3];
pamount=tokens[4];
status=tokens[5];
fileread=br.readLine();
LoginInfo lo=new LoginInfo(id,accountid,name,type,pamount,status);
witharraylist.add(lo);
}

System.out.println("1----Fast Cash");
System.out.println("2----Normal Cash");
System.out.println("3----Exit");
System.out.println("Enter your Choice:"); 
choice1 = reader.next().charAt(0);
switch(choice1)
{
case'1':
System.out.println("1----500"); 
System.out.println("2----1000"); 
System.out.println("3----2000"); 
System.out.println("4----5000"); 
System.out.println("5----10000"); 
System.out.println("6----15000"); 
System.out.println("7----20000 ");

System.out.println("Select one of the denominations of money:"); 
choice2 = reader.next().charAt(0);
if(choice2=='1')
{
System.out.println("Are you sure you want to withdraw Rs.500 (Y/N)?");
confirm = reader.next().charAt(0);
if (confirm=='y'||confirm=='Y')
{
String get=obj2.setid;
for(int i=0;i<witharraylist.size();i++)
{
LoginInfo low=(LoginInfo)witharraylist.get(i);
if(get.equals(low.pid))                                                           
{

withdrawalbal=500;
actualbal=low.amount;
cactualbal=Integer.parseInt(actualbal);
availablebal=cactualbal-withdrawalbal;
cavailablebal=Integer.toString(availablebal);
System.out.println("Your Available balance:"+cavailablebal);
witharraylist.set(i,low);
writeValues();
}
}

}
else
{

System.out.println("Transfer not successfully");
withDrawal();
}
}
break;
}
}catch(IOException ex)
{
System.out.println(ex);

}
}
public void writeValues()
{
try{
String line;
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("account.txt");
PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(fw);
for(int i=0;i<witharraylist.size();i++){
LoginInfo wr=(LoginInfo)witharraylist.get(i);

line=wr.pid+","+wr.accountid+","+wr.name+","+wr.type+","+wr.amount+","+wr.status;
pw.println(line);``

}

pw.flush();
fw.close();
pw.close();![this is the image of error][1]
}catch(IOException ex)
{
System.out.println(ex);
}
}
}
<code>
```

Comment: One possibility of `tokens` having less than 6 elements. It would be helpful if you can post the stack trace of error

Comment: *So* many problems. Formatting, no generics, no stack trace...

Comment: Add Stacktrace and markt the line where the exception comes from!

Comment: no no Mass token has 6 elements not have less than 6

Comment: **Mass** i have post stack trace of error

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
while (fileread!=null)
{
  tokens=fileread.split(",");
  if (tokens.length >= 6) {
    id=tokens[0];
    accountid=tokens[1];
    name=tokens[2];
    type=tokens[3];
    pamount=tokens[4];
    status=tokens[5];
    LoginInfo lo=new LoginInfo(id,accountid,name,type,pamount,status);
    witharraylist.add(lo);
  } 
  else {
     System.out.println ("Oh dear!!");
  }

  fileread=br.readLine();

}
```

Comment: hy can u explain the reason

Comment: maybe you have some blank or wrong formatted lines within your text file.  Also consider using an opensource csvreader.

Comment: my error remove due to you thank u very much but i cant understand how will work cn u elaburate ur code for making my new concept

Comment: what is mean if (tokens.length>=6)?

Comment: it test to see if after you split the line, there are at least six tokens

Comment: thank u very much do u have facebook id i want to add u if you dont mine

Answer (score 0):

there may be a problem with the text file account.txt like less number of commas(,). Please check them because you are using the split function.

Comment: dude in account file in one line have 5 commas i think this is alright